# Binomial distribution in python

Tags: python, statistics, probability

So, I have a very simple program, as follows:

```
from scipy.stats import binom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

for x in range(10,20):
    p = sum(np.random.binomial(30,0.5,100000)==x)/100000

print(p)
```

The idea is, given a random walk with equal probability of going left or right, what is the probability that there will be between 10-20 steps to the right. Seems simple enough, and if I set x to 15 instead, it does, in fact, produce the correct answer. But when I set it for this particular range, it gives me ~5%, which is wrong. Should be closer to 100%. What do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"sum()" does not give you a running sum for the life of a loop: it sums the items within the parentheses.  You're getting only the last split, the one for x==19.  Try this:

```
p = 0.0
for x in range(10,20):
    p += sum(np.random.binomial(30,0.5,100000)==x)/100000
```

Comment: Awesome answer. I'm curious, though, as to why it was necessary to set p = 0.0 at the beginning.

Comment: That's the value of p before you add anything to it.
Python does not initialize variables for you.